# Can't deploy with guava dependencies because of invalid checksums in typesafe releases repo

Tags: java, heroku, guava

I'm getting an error deploying my app to Heroku because of an "unresolved dependencies" error for com.google.guava#guava-base;r03 and com.google.guava#guava-annotaions;r03. When I try to get one of the jars manually with the URL:

http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/google/guava/guava-base/r03/guava-base-r03.jar

I get the below errors.  It looks like the checksums are wrong for this artifact in the typesafe releases repo.  Does anyone know how to fix or work around this issue?  Thanks!

> HTTP Status 409 - Rejected artifact download request: Checksum policy
>   'GEN_IF_ABSENT' rejected the artifact 'guava-base-r03.jar'. Checksums
>   info: [ChecksumInfo{type=SHA-1,
>   original='cb713fb4e84bd3c82cb71dece3c123563ed2643e',
>   actual='251db72895ba5745e6810334075095832f12f437'},
>   ChecksumInfo{type=MD5, original='1384456aeec4d4c8cc2bff9227766a4e',
>   actual='4bb26509e6e43a603b4e2f17161fbbc5'}]
>
> type Status report
>
> message Rejected artifact download request: Checksum policy
>   'GEN_IF_ABSENT' rejected the artifact 'guava-base-r03.jar'. Checksums
>   info: [ChecksumInfo{type=SHA-1,
>   original='cb713fb4e84bd3c82cb71dece3c123563ed2643e',
>   actual='251db72895ba5745e6810334075095832f12f437'},
>   ChecksumInfo{type=MD5, original='1384456aeec4d4c8cc2bff9227766a4e',
>   actual='4bb26509e6e43a603b4e2f17161fbbc5'}]
>
> description The request could not be completed due to a conflict with
>   the current state of the resource (Rejected artifact download request:
>   Checksum policy 'GEN_IF_ABSENT' rejected the artifact
>   'guava-base-r03.jar'. Checksums info: [ChecksumInfo{type=SHA-1,
>   original='cb713fb4e84bd3c82cb71dece3c123563ed2643e',
>   actual='251db72895ba5745e6810334075095832f12f437'},
>   ChecksumInfo{type=MD5, original='1384456aeec4d4c8cc2bff9227766a4e',
>   actual='4bb26509e6e43a603b4e2f17161fbbc5'}]).
>
> Apache Tomcat/7.0.26

Comment: I found an ugly work around, which is to disable checksum checking and change the default resolvers: `val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion,appDependencies).settings(defaultScalaSettings:_*).settings(checksums in update := Nil,resolvers := Seq(DefaultMavenRepository))`.  I'd still like some help on getting the checksums fixed on the guava artifacts so I can re-enable checksum checking. Thanks

Comment: You could try excluding the dependency, since r03 is pretty old, and fetching from central

Answer (score 1):

Per the suggestion above I was able to resolve this issue by excluding the transient dependency I had from bitcoinj -> guava-base r03 and adding a new dependency to guava 13.0. I also went back to using the default resolvers and checksum checking. My new Build.scala appDependencies looks like this:

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
    "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "13.0",
    "com.google" % "bitcoinj" % "0.5.1" exclude("com.google.guava", "guava"),
    "org.squeryl" %% "squeryl" % "0.9.5-2",
    "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901.jdbc4"
)

val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion,
           appDependencies).settings(defaultScalaSettings:_*)
```

I am now able to deploy my app to Heroku with no problems.  Thanks Ben for the useful tip!